# Powershell: Adding contraints /define format for variable/Read-Host in console menu eg. must be enclosed in quotes etc

Tags: variables, powershell, menu, console, constraints

I'm using a console menu to restore deleted items from the AD recycle bin.

There are 4 menu options, each of them requiring user input (read-host) but it needs to be in the correct format or the restore won't work. Is there a way to define constraints for each variable/read-host in the console menu?

Here is my menu

```
#Keep looping and running the menu until the user selects Q (or q).
Do {
#use a Switch construct to take action depending on what menu choice
#is selected.
Switch (Show-Menu $menu " `nActive Directory Restore AD Tree Menu" -clear) {
 "1" {Write-Host " `nRestore AD Tree using LastKnownRDN" -ForegroundColor Yellow
     $RDN=Read-Host " `nEnter LastKnownRDN of deleted object (eg. STAFF) "
     .\Restore_ADTree.ps1 Restore-ADTree -lastknownRDN $RDN
     sleep -seconds 2
     } 
 "2" {Write-Host "Restore AD Tree using LastKnownRDN and LastKnownParent" -ForegroundColor Green
     $RDN=Read-Host " `nEnter LastKnownRDN of deleted object (eg. STAFF) "
     $LNP=Read-Host " `nEnter LastKnownParent of deleted object in quotes (eg. "OU=Staff,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx")"
     .\Restore_ADTree.ps1 Restore-ADTree -lastknownRDN $RDN -lastknownParent $LNP
      sleep -seconds 5
      }
 "3" {Write-Host "Restore AD Tree Using Identity Distinguished Name" -ForegroundColor Magenta
     $DName=Read-Host " `nEnter the Distinguished Name of deleted object (eg. "OU=Test,OU=Staff,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx") "
     .\Restore_ADTree.ps1 Restore-ADTree -identity $DName
     sleep -seconds 2
     }
 "4" {Write-Host "Restore AD Tree Using Identity GUID"
     $GUID=Read-Host " `nEnter the GUID of deleted object (eg. b48290aa-e14f-4417-9c03-560a546d18b9) "
     .\Restore_ADTree.ps1 Restore-ADTree -identity $GUID
     sleep -seconds 2    
     }
 "Q" {Write-Host "Goodbye" -ForegroundColor Cyan
     Return
     }
 Default {Write-Warning "Invalid Choice. Try again."
          sleep -milliseconds 750}
} #switch
} While ($True)
```

So for 2. I'd like to ensure $LNP is in quotes

For 3. I'd like the input to at least contain DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX and to be enclosed in quotes

For 4. I'd like to ensure it's in xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx no special characters.

I'd also like to be able to write to the console if they got it wrong with a message about what format it needs to be in.

If someone could please point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Amelia

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `Read-Host` implementation, something like this:

```
function MyRead-Host($prompt, $regex)
{
    while(!$inputOk)    {   $inputOk = (IsInputOk (Read-Host -Prompt $prompt) $regex)   }   
}

function IsInputOk([string] $string, [string] $regex)
{
    if ($string -eq $regex) { return $true  } return $false
}
```

This particular implementation will ask user for input until it will be equal to `$regex` variable. You should do some smart Regex matching if you want to have generic function, otherwise yo can write own validator for each case